# Jackrabbit Text search in Arabic PDF File

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I am able to perform text search for arabic text file successfully using the following code in Jackrabbit. But for an Arabic PDF file, the same search is not working. If I give some of the non-arabic text inside the fle, its giving me the correct result, but if I give an araic word inside the file, its not giving me any result.

```
Query query = queryManager.createQuery("select * from [nt:resource] AS resource where contains(resource.*, '%القط%')", Query.JCR_SQL2);

 QueryResult result = query.execute();
 RowIterator ri = result.getRows();

     while (ri.hasNext()) {      
     Row row = ri.nextRow(); 
     System.out.println("Row: " + row.toString()); 
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly PDFBox could not parse the file. [In this case, there should be a warning in the log file](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Search#Fulltext_Indexing_of_Chinese.2C_Japanese_and_Korea).

Comment: Yes I got that warning while adding the PDF file in the repository. But can you tell me what I can do to make the PDFBox parse the file with Arabic content?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer this question as I'm not familiar with PDFBox. A quick Google search did gave a few results however, and it seems newer versions (maybe still beta) of PDFBox should be able to parse it. If not, please ask at the PDFBox list, or ask another question here.